# Autodesk Forge is returning odd measurement data

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I've been developing an app that uses translated Revit files to display data of various elements to users. We display dimension data in meters, so whenever an element has its dimensions measured in something like millimeters, I of course run a simple conversion.

Recently, this conversion began failing, and upon inspection, this happens because the file no longer outputs the element's dimension data in mm, but rather as a file format to the tune of "autodesk.unit.unit:millimeters-1.0.1" or similar for meters and square meters.

Does anyone know if this is intended for current and future use? I've confirmed this happens even with files that were created as far back as a couple of years when translated to Forge today.

See attached [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2PSo.jpg) for a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this probably intended, cf. the [Revit 2021 Unit API changes](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2021-api.html#4.1.3).

Revit 2021 switched to a new convention for handling units, to be better aligned with Forge and other cloud applications.

This is intended to simplify your work, not make it harder.

Sorry if the initial switch causes some extra effort for you.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a new test method `ListForgeTypeIds` in [The Building Coder samples](https://github.com/jeremytammik/the_building_coder_samples) to list all the `ForgeTypeId` specs and units, cf. the [diff to the previous release](https://github.com/jeremytammik/the_building_coder_samples/compare/2021.0.150.8...2021.0.150.9).

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, here is the full code to list the `ForgeTypeId` specs and units defined in Revit:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List all Forge type ids
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="doc"></param>
    public static void ListForgeTypeIds()
    {
      //ForgeTypeId a = SpecTypeId.Acceleration;
      //Debug.Print( a.TypeId );

      Type spityp = typeof( SpecTypeId );

      //foreach( MemberInfo mi in spityp.GetMembers() )
      //{
      //  Debug.Print( mi.Name );
      //}

      PropertyInfo[] ps = spityp.GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );

      // Sort properties alphabetically by name 

      Array.Sort( ps, 
        delegate( PropertyInfo p1, PropertyInfo p2 )
          { return p1.Name.CompareTo( p2.Name ); } );

      Debug.Print( "{0} properties:", ps.Length );

      foreach( PropertyInfo pi in ps )
      {
        if( pi.PropertyType == typeof( ForgeTypeId ) )
        {
          object obj = pi.GetValue( null, null);

          ForgeTypeId fti = obj as ForgeTypeId;

          Debug.Print( "{0}: {1}", pi.Name, fti.TypeId );
        }
      }

      IList<ForgeTypeId> specs = UnitUtils.GetAllSpecs();

      Debug.Print( "{0} specs:", specs.Count );

      foreach( ForgeTypeId fti in specs )
      {
        Debug.Print( "{0}: {1}, {2}", 
          fti.ToString(), fti.TypeId, 
          UnitUtils.GetTypeCatalogStringForSpec( fti ) );
      }

      IList<ForgeTypeId> units = UnitUtils.GetAllUnits();

      Debug.Print( "{0} units:", units.Count );

      foreach( ForgeTypeId fti in units )
      {
        Debug.Print( "{0}: {1}, {2}",
          fti.ToString(), fti.TypeId,
          UnitUtils.GetTypeCatalogStringForUnit( fti ) );
      }
    }
```

Here are the lists produced by that code, slightly edited for readability:

```
  Type spityp = typeof( SpecTypeId );
  PropertyInfo[] ps = spityp.GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );
```

This returns 149 properties (PropertyInfo.Name: ForgeTypeId.TypeId):

```
Acceleration: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:acceleration-1.0.0
AirFlow: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:airFlow-1.0.1
AirFlowDensity: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:airFlowDensity-1.0.1
AirFlowDividedByCoolingLoad: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:airFlowDividedByCoolingLoad-1.0.0
AirFlowDividedByVolume: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:airFlowDividedByVolume-1.0.1
Angle: autodesk.spec.aec:angle-1.0.0
AngularSpeed: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:angularSpeed-1.0.1
ApparentPower: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:apparentPower-1.0.0
Area: autodesk.spec.aec:area-1.0.0
AreaDividedByCoolingLoad: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:areaDividedByCoolingLoad-1.0.0
AreaDividedByHeatingLoad: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:areaDividedByHeatingLoad-1.0.1
AreaForce: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:areaForce-1.0.0
AreaForceScale: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:areaForceScale-1.0.0
AreaSpringCoefficient: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:areaSpringCoefficient-1.0.0
BarDiameter: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:barDiameter-1.0.0
CableTraySize: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:cableTraySize-1.0.0
ColorTemperature: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:colorTemperature-1.0.0
ConduitSize: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:conduitSize-1.0.0
CoolingLoad: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:coolingLoad-1.0.0
CoolingLoadDividedByArea: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:coolingLoadDividedByArea-1.0.0
CoolingLoadDividedByVolume: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:coolingLoadDividedByVolume-1.0.0
CostPerArea: autodesk.spec.aec:costPerArea-1.0.0
CostRateEnergy: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:costRateEnergy-1.0.0
CostRatePower: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:costRatePower-1.0.0
CrackWidth: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:crackWidth-1.0.0
CrossSection: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:crossSection-1.0.0
Currency: autodesk.spec.measurable:currency-1.0.0
Current: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:current-1.0.0
Custom: autodesk.spec:custom-1.0.0
DecimalSheetLength: autodesk.spec.aec:decimalSheetLength-1.0.0
DemandFactor: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:demandFactor-1.0.0
Diffusivity: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:diffusivity-1.0.0
Displacement: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:displacement-1.0.0
Distance: autodesk.spec.aec:distance-1.0.0
DuctInsulationThickness: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:ductInsulationThickness-1.0.0
DuctLiningThickness: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:ductLiningThickness-1.0.0
DuctSize: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:ductSize-1.0.0
Efficacy: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:efficacy-1.0.0
ElectricalFrequency: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:frequency-1.0.0
ElectricalPotential: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:potential-1.0.0
ElectricalPower: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:power-1.0.1
ElectricalPowerDensity: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:powerDensity-1.0.0
ElectricalResistivity: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:resistivity-1.0.0
ElectricalTemperature: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:temperature-1.0.0
ElectricalTemperatureDifference: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:temperatureDifference-1.0.0
Energy: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:energy-1.0.0
Factor: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:factor-1.0.0
Flow: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:flow-1.0.0
FlowPerPower: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:flowPerPower-1.0.0
Force: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:force-1.0.1
ForceScale: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:forceScale-1.0.0
HeatGain: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:heatGain-1.0.0
HeatingLoad: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:heatingLoad-1.0.0
HeatingLoadDividedByArea: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:heatingLoadDividedByArea-1.0.0
HeatingLoadDividedByVolume: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:heatingLoadDividedByVolume-1.0.0
HeatTransferCoefficient: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:heatTransferCoefficient-1.0.0
HvacDensity: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:density-1.0.0
HvacEnergy: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:energy-1.0.0
HvacFriction: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:friction-1.0.2
HvacMassPerTime: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:massPerTime-1.0.0
HvacPower: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:power-1.0.0
HvacPowerDensity: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:powerDensity-1.0.0
HvacPressure: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:pressure-1.0.2
HvacRoughness: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:roughness-1.0.0
HvacSlope: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:slope-1.0.2
HvacTemperature: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:temperature-1.0.0
HvacTemperatureDifference: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:temperatureDifference-1.0.0
HvacVelocity: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:velocity-1.0.1
HvacViscosity: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:viscosity-1.0.1
Illuminance: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:illuminance-1.0.0
IsothermalMoistureCapacity: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:isothermalMoistureCapacity-1.0.0
Length: autodesk.spec.aec:length-1.0.0
LinearForce: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:linearForce-1.0.0
LinearForceScale: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:linearForceScale-1.0.0
LinearMoment: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:linearMoment-1.0.0
LinearMomentScale: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:linearMomentScale-1.0.0
LineSpringCoefficient: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:lineSpringCoefficient-1.0.0
Luminance: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:luminance-1.0.1
LuminousFlux: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:luminousFlux-1.0.0
LuminousIntensity: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:luminousIntensity-1.0.0
Mass: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:mass-1.0.0
MassDensity: autodesk.spec.aec:massDensity-1.0.0
MassPerUnitArea: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:massPerUnitArea-1.0.0
MassPerUnitLength: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:massPerUnitLength-1.0.0
Moment: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:moment-1.0.1
MomentOfInertia: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:momentOfInertia-1.0.0
MomentScale: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:momentScale-1.0.0
Number: autodesk.spec.aec:number-1.0.1
Period: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:period-1.0.0
Permeability: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:permeability-1.0.0
PipeDimension: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pipeDimension-1.0.0
PipeInsulationThickness: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pipeInsulationThickness-1.0.0
PipeMassPerUnitLength: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pipeMassPerUnitLength-1.0.0
PipeSize: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pipeSize-1.0.0
PipingDensity: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:density-1.0.0
PipingFriction: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:friction-1.0.2
PipingMass: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:mass-1.0.1
PipingMassPerTime: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:massPerTime-1.0.0
PipingPressure: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pressure-1.0.2
PipingRoughness: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:roughness-1.0.0
PipingSlope: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:slope-1.0.1
PipingTemperature: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:temperature-1.0.0
PipingTemperatureDifference: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:temperatureDifference-1.0.0
PipingVelocity: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:velocity-1.0.1
PipingViscosity: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:viscosity-1.0.1
PipingVolume: autodesk.spec.aec.piping:volume-1.0.0
PointSpringCoefficient: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:pointSpringCoefficient-1.0.0
PowerPerFlow: autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:powerPerFlow-1.0.0
PowerPerLength: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:powerPerLength-1.0.0
Pulsation: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:pulsation-1.0.0
ReinforcementArea: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementArea-1.0.0
ReinforcementAreaPerUnitLength: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementAreaPerUnitLength-1.0.0
ReinforcementCover: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementCover-1.0.0
ReinforcementLength: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementLength-1.0.0
ReinforcementSpacing: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementSpacing-1.0.0
ReinforcementVolume: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementVolume-1.0.0
Rotation: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:rotation-1.0.0
RotationalLineSpringCoefficient: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:rotationalLineSpringCoefficient-1.0.0
RotationalPointSpringCoefficient: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:rotationalPointSpringCoefficient-1.0.0
RotationAngle: autodesk.spec.aec:rotationAngle-1.0.1
SectionArea: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:sectionArea-1.0.0
SectionDimension: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:sectionDimension-1.0.0
SectionModulus: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:sectionModulus-1.0.0
SectionProperty: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:sectionProperty-1.0.0
SheetLength: autodesk.spec.aec:sheetLength-1.0.0
SiteAngle: autodesk.spec.aec:siteAngle-1.0.0
Slope: autodesk.spec.aec:slope-1.0.1
SpecificHeat: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:specificHeat-1.0.0
SpecificHeatOfVaporization: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:specificHeatOfVaporization-1.0.0
Speed: autodesk.spec.aec:speed-1.0.1
Stationing: autodesk.spec.aec.infrastructure:stationing-1.0.1
StationingInterval: autodesk.spec.aec.infrastructure:stationingInterval-1.0.0
Stress: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:stress-1.0.0
StructuralFrequency: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:frequency-1.0.0
StructuralVelocity: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:velocity-1.0.1
SurfaceAreaPerUnitLength: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:surfaceAreaPerUnitLength-1.0.0
ThermalConductivity: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:thermalConductivity-1.0.0
ThermalExpansionCoefficient: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:thermalExpansionCoefficient-1.0.0
ThermalGradientCoefficientForMoistureCapacity: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:thermalGradientCoefficientForMoistureCapacity-1.0.0
ThermalMass: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:thermalMass-1.0.0
ThermalResistance: autodesk.spec.aec.energy:thermalResistance-1.0.0
Time: autodesk.spec.aec:time-1.0.0
UnitWeight: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:unitWeight-1.0.0
Volume: autodesk.spec.aec:volume-1.0.0
WarpingConstant: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:warpingConstant-1.0.0
Wattage: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:wattage-1.0.0
Weight: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:weight-1.0.0
WeightPerUnitLength: autodesk.spec.aec.structural:weightPerUnitLength-1.0.0
WireDiameter: autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:wireDiameter-1.0.0
```

`UnitUtils.GetAllSpecs()` returns 148 specs (`TypeId`, `UnitUtils.GetTypeCatalogStringForSpec`):

```
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:apparentPower-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_APPARENT_POWER
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:cableTraySize-1.0.0, CABLETRAY_SIZE
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:colorTemperature-1.0.0, COLOR_TEMPERATURE
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:conduitSize-1.0.0, CONDUIT_SIZE
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:costRateEnergy-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_COST_RATE_ENERGY
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:costRatePower-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_COST_RATE_POWER
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:current-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_CURRENT
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:demandFactor-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_DEMAND_FACTOR
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:efficacy-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_EFFICACY
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:frequency-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_FREQUENCY
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:illuminance-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_ILLUMINANCE
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:luminance-1.0.1, ELECTRICAL_LUMINANCE
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:luminousFlux-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_LUMINOUS_FLUX
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:luminousIntensity-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_LUMINOUS_INTENSITY
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:potential-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_POTENTIAL
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:power-1.0.1, ELECTRICAL_POWER
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:powerDensity-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_POWER_DENSITY
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:powerPerLength-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_POWER_PER_LENGTH
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:resistivity-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_RESISTIVITY
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:temperature-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_TEMPERATURE
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:temperatureDifference-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_TEMPERATURE_DIFFERENCE
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:wattage-1.0.0, ELECTRICAL_WATTAGE
autodesk.spec.aec.electrical:wireDiameter-1.0.0, WIRE_SIZE
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:energy-1.0.0, HVAC_ENERGY
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:heatTransferCoefficient-1.0.0, HVAC_COEFFICIENT_OF_HEAT_TRANSFER
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:isothermalMoistureCapacity-1.0.0, HVAC_ISOTHERMAL_MOISTURE_CAPACITY
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:permeability-1.0.0, HVAC_PERMEABILITY
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:specificHeat-1.0.0, HVAC_SPECIFIC_HEAT
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:specificHeatOfVaporization-1.0.0, HVAC_SPECIFIC_HEAT_OF_VAPORIZATION
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:thermalConductivity-1.0.0, HVAC_THERMAL_CONDUCTIVITY
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:thermalGradientCoefficientForMoistureCapacity-1.0.0, HVAC_THERMAL_GRADIENT_COEFFICIENT_FOR_MOISTURE_CAPACITY
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:thermalMass-1.0.0, HVAC_THERMAL_MASS
autodesk.spec.aec.energy:thermalResistance-1.0.0, HVAC_THERMAL_RESISTANCE
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:airFlow-1.0.1, HVAC_AIR_FLOW
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:airFlowDensity-1.0.1, HVAC_AIRFLOW_DENSITY
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:airFlowDividedByCoolingLoad-1.0.0, HVAC_AIRFLOW_DIVIDED_BY_COOLING_LOAD
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:airFlowDividedByVolume-1.0.1, HVAC_AIRFLOW_DIVIDED_BY_VOLUME
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:angularSpeed-1.0.1, HVAC_ANGULAR_SPEED
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:areaDividedByCoolingLoad-1.0.0, HVAC_AREA_DIVIDED_BY_COOLING_LOAD
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:areaDividedByHeatingLoad-1.0.1, HVAC_AREA_DIVIDED_BY_HEATING_LOAD
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:coolingLoad-1.0.0, HVAC_COOLING_LOAD
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:coolingLoadDividedByArea-1.0.0, HVAC_COOLING_LOAD_DIVIDED_BY_AREA
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:coolingLoadDividedByVolume-1.0.0, HVAC_COOLING_LOAD_DIVIDED_BY_VOLUME
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:crossSection-1.0.0, HVAC_CROSS_SECTION
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:density-1.0.0, HVAC_DENSITY
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:diffusivity-1.0.0, HVAC_DIFFUSIVITY
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:ductInsulationThickness-1.0.0, HVAC_DUCT_INSULATION_THICKNESS
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:ductLiningThickness-1.0.0, HVAC_DUCT_LINING_THICKNESS
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:ductSize-1.0.0, HVAC_DUCT_SIZE
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:factor-1.0.0, HVAC_FACTOR
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:flowPerPower-1.0.0, HVAC_FLOW_PER_POWER
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:friction-1.0.2, HVAC_FRICTION
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:heatGain-1.0.0, HVAC_HEAT_GAIN
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:heatingLoad-1.0.0, HVAC_HEATING_LOAD
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:heatingLoadDividedByArea-1.0.0, HVAC_HEATING_LOAD_DIVIDED_BY_AREA
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:heatingLoadDividedByVolume-1.0.0, HVAC_HEATING_LOAD_DIVIDED_BY_VOLUME
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:massPerTime-1.0.0, HVAC_MASS_PER_TIME
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:power-1.0.0, HVAC_POWER
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:powerDensity-1.0.0, HVAC_POWER_DENSITY
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:powerPerFlow-1.0.0, HVAC_POWER_PER_FLOW
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:pressure-1.0.2, HVAC_PRESSURE
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:roughness-1.0.0, HVAC_ROUGHNESS
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:slope-1.0.2, HVAC_SLOPE
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:temperature-1.0.0, HVAC_TEMPERATURE
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:temperatureDifference-1.0.0, HVAC_TEMPERATURE_DIFFERENCE
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:velocity-1.0.1, HVAC_VELOCITY
autodesk.spec.aec.hvac:viscosity-1.0.1, HVAC_VISCOSITY
autodesk.spec.aec.infrastructure:stationing-1.0.1, STATIONING
autodesk.spec.aec.infrastructure:stationingInterval-1.0.0, STATIONING_INTERVAL
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:density-1.0.0, PIPING_DENSITY
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:flow-1.0.0, PIPING_FLOW
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:friction-1.0.2, PIPING_FRICTION
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:mass-1.0.1, PIPE_MASS
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:massPerTime-1.0.0, PIPING_MASS_PER_TIME
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pipeDimension-1.0.0, PIPE_DIMENSION
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pipeInsulationThickness-1.0.0, PIPE_INSUlATION_THICKNESS
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pipeMassPerUnitLength-1.0.0, PIPE_MASS_PER_UNIT_LENGTH
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pipeSize-1.0.0, PIPE_SIZE
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:pressure-1.0.2, PIPING_PRESSURE
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:roughness-1.0.0, PIPING_ROUGHNESS
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:slope-1.0.1, PIPING_SLOPE
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:temperature-1.0.0, PIPING_TEMPERATURE
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:temperatureDifference-1.0.0, PIPING_TEMPERATURE_DIFFERENCE
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:velocity-1.0.1, PIPING_VELOCITY
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:viscosity-1.0.1, PIPING_VISCOSITY
autodesk.spec.aec.piping:volume-1.0.0, PIPING_VOLUME
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:acceleration-1.0.0, ACCELERATION
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:areaForce-1.0.0, AREA_FORCE
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:areaForceScale-1.0.0, AREA_FORCE_SCALE
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:areaSpringCoefficient-1.0.0, AREA_SPRING_COEFFICIENT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:barDiameter-1.0.0, BAR_DIAMETER
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:crackWidth-1.0.0, CRACK_WIDTH
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:displacement-1.0.0, DISPLACEMENT/DEFLECTION
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:energy-1.0.0, ENERGY
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:force-1.0.1, FORCE
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:forceScale-1.0.0, FORCE_SCALE
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:frequency-1.0.0, STRUCTURAL_FREQUENCY
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:lineSpringCoefficient-1.0.0, LINEAR_SPRING_COEFFICIENT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:linearForce-1.0.0, LINEAR_FORCE
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:linearForceScale-1.0.0, LINEAR_FORCE_SCALE
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:linearMoment-1.0.0, LINEAR_MOMENT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:linearMomentScale-1.0.0, LINEAR_MOMENT_SCALE
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:mass-1.0.0, MASS
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:massPerUnitArea-1.0.0, MASS_PER_UNIT_AREA
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:massPerUnitLength-1.0.0, MASS_PER_UNIT_LENGTH
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:moment-1.0.1, MOMENT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:momentOfInertia-1.0.0, MOMENT_OF_INERTIA
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:momentScale-1.0.0, MOMENT_SCALE
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:period-1.0.0, PERIOD
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:pointSpringCoefficient-1.0.0, POINT_SPRING_COEFFICIENT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:pulsation-1.0.0, PULSATION
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementArea-1.0.0, REINFORCEMENT_AREA
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementAreaPerUnitLength-1.0.0, REINFORCEMENT_AREA_PER_UNIT_LENGTH
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementCover-1.0.0, REINFORCEMENT_COVER
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementLength-1.0.0, REINFORCEMENT_LENGTH
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementSpacing-1.0.0, REINFORCEMENT_SPACING
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:reinforcementVolume-1.0.0, REINFORCEMENT_VOLUME
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:rotation-1.0.0, ROTATION
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:rotationalLineSpringCoefficient-1.0.0, ROTATIONAL_LINEAR_SPRING_COEFFICIENT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:rotationalPointSpringCoefficient-1.0.0, ROTATIONAL_POINT_SPRING_COEFFICIENT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:sectionArea-1.0.0, SECTION_AREA
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:sectionDimension-1.0.0, SECTION_DIMENSION
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:sectionModulus-1.0.0, SECTION_MODULUS
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:sectionProperty-1.0.0, SECTION_PROPERTY
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:stress-1.0.0, STRESS
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:surfaceAreaPerUnitLength-1.0.0, SURFACE_AREA
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:thermalExpansionCoefficient-1.0.0, THERMAL_EXPANSION_COEFFICIENT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:unitWeight-1.0.0, UNIT_WEIGHT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:velocity-1.0.1, VELOCITY
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:warpingConstant-1.0.0, WARPING_CONSTANT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:weight-1.0.0, WEIGHT
autodesk.spec.aec.structural:weightPerUnitLength-1.0.0, WEIGHT_PER_UNIT_LENGTH
autodesk.spec.aec:angle-1.0.0, ANGLE
autodesk.spec.aec:area-1.0.0, AREA
autodesk.spec.aec:costPerArea-1.0.0, COST_PER_AREA
autodesk.spec.aec:decimalSheetLength-1.0.0, PEN SIZE
autodesk.spec.aec:distance-1.0.0, DISTANCE
autodesk.spec.aec:length-1.0.0, LENGTH
autodesk.spec.aec:massDensity-1.0.0, MASS_DENSITY
autodesk.spec.aec:number-1.0.1, NUMBER
autodesk.spec.aec:rotationAngle-1.0.1, ROTATION_ANGLE
autodesk.spec.aec:sheetLength-1.0.0, PAPER LENGTH
autodesk.spec.aec:siteAngle-1.0.0, SITE_ANGLE
autodesk.spec.aec:slope-1.0.1, SLOPE
autodesk.spec.aec:speed-1.0.1, SPEED
autodesk.spec.aec:time-1.0.0, TIMEINTERVAL
autodesk.spec.aec:volume-1.0.0, VOLUME
autodesk.spec.measurable:currency-1.0.0, CURRENCY
```

Answer (score 0):

Continued...

`UnitUtils.GetAllUnits()` returns 340 units (`TypeId`, `UnitUtils.GetTypeCatalogStringForSpec`):

```
autodesk.unit.unit:1ToRatio-1.0.1, RATIO1
autodesk.unit.unit:acres-1.0.1, ACRES
autodesk.unit.unit:amperes-1.0.0, AMPERES
autodesk.unit.unit:atmospheres-1.0.1, ATMOSPHERES
autodesk.unit.unit:bars-1.0.1, BARS
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnits-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerDegreeFahrenheit-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_DEGREE_FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerHour-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerHourCubicFoot-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_HOUR_CUBIC_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerHourFootDegreeFahrenheit-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_HOUR_FOOT_DEGREE_FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerHourSquareFoot-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_HOUR_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerHourSquareFootDegreeFahrenheit-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_HOUR_SQUARE_FOOT_DEGREE_FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerPound-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_POUND
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerPoundDegreeFahrenheit-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_POUND_DEGREE_FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:britishThermalUnitsPerSecond-1.0.1, BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:calories-1.0.1, CALORIES
autodesk.unit.unit:caloriesPerSecond-1.0.1, CALORIES_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:candelas-1.0.0, CANDELAS
autodesk.unit.unit:candelasPerSquareFoot-1.0.0, CANDELAS_PER_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:candelasPerSquareMeter-1.0.1, CANDELAS_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:celsius-1.0.1, CELSIUS
autodesk.unit.unit:celsiusInterval-1.0.1, CELSIUS_INTERVAL
autodesk.unit.unit:centimeters-1.0.1, CENTIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:centimetersPerMinute-1.0.1, CENTIMETERS_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:centimetersToTheFourthPower-1.0.1, CENTIMETERS_TO_THE_FOURTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:centimetersToTheSixthPower-1.0.1, CENTIMETERS_TO_THE_SIXTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:centipoises-1.0.1, CENTIPOISES
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicCentimeters-1.0.1, CUBIC_CENTIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeet-1.0.1, CUBIC_FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeetPerHour-1.0.0, CUBIC_FEET_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeetPerKip-1.0.1, CUBIC_FEET_PER_KIP
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeetPerMinute-1.0.1, CUBIC_FEET_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeetPerMinuteCubicFoot-1.0.1, CUBIC_FEET_PER_MINUTE_CUBIC_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeetPerMinutePerBritishThermalUnitPerHour-1.0.0, CUBIC_FEET_PER_MINUTE_PER_BRITISH_THERMAL_UNIT_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeetPerMinuteSquareFoot-1.0.1, CUBIC_FEET_PER_MINUTE_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeetPerMinuteTonOfRefrigeration-1.0.1, CUBIC_FEET_PER_MINUTE_TON_OF_REFRIGERATION
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicFeetPerPoundMass-1.0.0, CUBIC_FEET_PER_POUND_MASS
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicInches-1.0.1, CUBIC_INCHES
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMeters-1.0.1, CUBIC_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMetersPerHour-1.0.1, CUBIC_METERS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMetersPerHourCubicMeter-1.0.0, CUBIC_METERS_PER_HOUR_CUBIC_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMetersPerHourSquareMeter-1.0.0, CUBIC_METERS_PER_HOUR_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMetersPerKilogram-1.0.0, CUBIC_METERS_PER_KILOGRAM
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMetersPerKilonewton-1.0.1, CUBIC_METERS_PER_KILONEWTON
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMetersPerSecond-1.0.1, CUBIC_METERS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMetersPerWattSecond-1.0.0, CUBIC_METERS_PER_WATT_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicMillimeters-1.0.1, CUBIC_MILLIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:cubicYards-1.0.1, CUBIC_YARDS
autodesk.unit.unit:currency-1.0.0, CURRENCY
autodesk.unit.unit:currencyPerBritishThermalUnit-1.0.1, COST_PER_BRITISH_THERMAL_UNIT
autodesk.unit.unit:currencyPerBritishThermalUnitPerHour-1.0.1, COST_PER_BRITISH_THERMAL_UNIT_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:currencyPerSquareFoot-1.0.1, COST_PER_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:currencyPerSquareMeter-1.0.1, COST_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:currencyPerWatt-1.0.1, COST_PER_WATT
autodesk.unit.unit:currencyPerWattHour-1.0.1, COST_PER_WATT_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:cyclesPerSecond-1.0.1, CYCLES_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:decimeters-1.0.1, DECIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:degrees-1.0.1, DEGREES
autodesk.unit.unit:dekanewtonMeters-1.0.1, DEKANEWTON_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:dekanewtonMetersPerMeter-1.0.1, DEKANEWTON_METERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:dekanewtons-1.0.1, DEKANEWTONS
autodesk.unit.unit:dekanewtonsPerMeter-1.0.1, DEKANEWTONS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:dekanewtonsPerSquareMeter-1.0.1, DEKANEWTONS_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:fahrenheit-1.0.1, FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:fahrenheitInterval-1.0.1, FAHRENHEIT_INTERVAL
autodesk.unit.unit:feet-1.0.1, FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:feetOfWater39.2DegreesFahrenheit-1.0.1, FEET_OF_WATER
autodesk.unit.unit:feetOfWater39.2DegreesFahrenheitPer100Feet-1.0.1, FEET_OF_WATER_PER_100FT
autodesk.unit.unit:feetPerKip-1.0.0, FEET_PER_KIP
autodesk.unit.unit:feetPerMinute-1.0.1, FEET_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:feetPerSecond-1.0.1, FEET_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:feetPerSecondSquared-1.0.1, FEET_PER_SECOND_SQUARED
autodesk.unit.unit:feetToTheFourthPower-1.0.1, FEET_TO_THE_FOURTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:feetToTheSixthPower-1.0.1, FEET_TO_THE_SIXTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:fixed-1.0.1, FIXED
autodesk.unit.unit:footcandles-1.0.1, FOOTCANDLES
autodesk.unit.unit:footlamberts-1.0.1, FOOTLAMBERTS
autodesk.unit.unit:general-1.0.1, GENERAL
autodesk.unit.unit:gradians-1.0.1, GRADIANS
autodesk.unit.unit:grains-1.0.1, GRAINS
autodesk.unit.unit:grainsPerHourSquareFootInchMercury-1.0.1, GRAINS_PER_HOUR_SQUARE_FOOT_INCH_MERCURY
autodesk.unit.unit:grams-1.0.1, GRAMS
autodesk.unit.unit:hectares-1.0.1, HECTARES
autodesk.unit.unit:hectometers-1.0.1, HECTOMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:hertz-1.0.1, HERTZ
autodesk.unit.unit:horsepower-1.0.1, HORSEPOWER
autodesk.unit.unit:hourSquareFootDegreesFahrenheitPerBritishThermalUnit-1.0.1, HOUR_SQUARE_FOOT_DEGREES_FAHRENHEIT_PER_BRITISH_THERMAL_UNIT
autodesk.unit.unit:hours-1.0.1, HOURS
autodesk.unit.unit:inches-1.0.1, INCHES
autodesk.unit.unit:inchesOfMercury32DegreesFahrenheit-1.0.1, INCHES_OF_MERCURY
autodesk.unit.unit:inchesOfWater60DegreesFahrenheit-1.0.1, INCHES_OF_WATER
autodesk.unit.unit:inchesOfWater60DegreesFahrenheitPer100Feet-1.0.1, INCHES_OF_WATER_PER_100FT
autodesk.unit.unit:inchesPerSecond-1.0.1, INCHES_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:inchesPerSecondSquared-1.0.1, INCHES_PER_SECOND_SQUARED
autodesk.unit.unit:inchesToTheFourthPower-1.0.1, INCHES_TO_THE_FOURTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:inchesToTheSixthPower-1.0.1, INCHES_TO_THE_SIXTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:inverseDegreesCelsius-1.0.1, INVERSE_DEGREES_CELSIUS
autodesk.unit.unit:inverseDegreesFahrenheit-1.0.1, INVERSE_DEGREES_FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:inverseKilonewtons-1.0.0, INVERSE_KILONEWTONS
autodesk.unit.unit:inverseKips-1.0.0, INVERSE_KIPS
autodesk.unit.unit:joules-1.0.1, JOULES
autodesk.unit.unit:joulesPerGram-1.0.1, JOULES_PER_GRAM
autodesk.unit.unit:joulesPerGramDegreeCelsius-1.0.1, JOULES_PER_GRAM_DEGREE_CELSIUS
autodesk.unit.unit:joulesPerKelvin-1.0.1, JOULES_PER_KELVIN
autodesk.unit.unit:joulesPerKilogram-1.0.1, JOULES_PER_KILOGRAM
autodesk.unit.unit:joulesPerKilogramDegreeCelsius-1.0.1, JOULES_PER_KILOGRAM_DEGREE_CELSIUS
autodesk.unit.unit:kelvin-1.0.0, KELVIN
autodesk.unit.unit:kelvinInterval-1.0.0, KELVIN_INTERVAL
autodesk.unit.unit:kiloamperes-1.0.1, KILOAMPERES
autodesk.unit.unit:kilocalories-1.0.1, KILOCALORIES
autodesk.unit.unit:kilocaloriesPerSecond-1.0.1, KILOCALORIES_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramForceMeters-1.0.1, KILOGRAM_FORCE_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramForceMetersPerMeter-1.0.1, KILOGRAM_FORCE_METERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramKelvins-1.0.0, KILOGRAM_KELVINS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilograms-1.0.0, KILOGRAMS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsForce-1.0.1, KILOGRAMS_FORCE
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsForcePerMeter-1.0.1, KILOGRAMS_FORCE_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsForcePerSquareMeter-1.0.1, KILOGRAMS_FORCE_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerCubicMeter-1.0.1, KILOGRAMS_PER_CUBIC_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerHour-1.0.0, KILOGRAMS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerKilogramKelvin-1.0.0, KILOGRAMS_PER_KILOGRAM_KELVIN
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerMeter-1.0.1, KILOGRAMS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerMeterHour-1.0.0, KILOGRAMS_PER_METER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerMeterSecond-1.0.0, KILOGRAMS_PER_METER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerMinute-1.0.0, KILOGRAMS_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerSecond-1.0.0, KILOGRAMS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:kilogramsPerSquareMeter-1.0.1, KILOGRAMS_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilojoules-1.0.1, KILOJOULES
autodesk.unit.unit:kilojoulesPerKelvin-1.0.1, KILOJOULES_PER_KELVIN
autodesk.unit.unit:kilometers-1.0.1, KILOMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilometersPerHour-1.0.1, KILOMETERS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:kilometersPerSecond-1.0.1, KILOMETERS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:kilometersPerSecondSquared-1.0.1, KILOMETERS_PER_SECOND_SQUARED
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonMeters-1.0.1, KILONEWTON_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonMetersPerDegree-1.0.1, KILONEWTON_METERS_PER_DEGREE
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonMetersPerDegreePerMeter-1.0.1, KILONEWTON_METERS_PER_DEGREE_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonMetersPerMeter-1.0.1, KILONEWTON_METERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtons-1.0.1, KILONEWTONS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonsPerCubicMeter-1.0.1, KILONEWTONS_PER_CUBIC_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonsPerMeter-1.0.1, KILONEWTONS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonsPerSquareCentimeter-1.0.1, KILONEWTONS_PER_SQUARE_CENTIMETER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonsPerSquareMeter-1.0.1, KILONEWTONS_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilonewtonsPerSquareMillimeter-1.0.1, KILONEWTONS_PER_SQUARE_MILLIMETER
autodesk.unit.unit:kilopascals-1.0.1, KILOPASCALS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilovoltAmperes-1.0.1, KILOVOLT_AMPERES
autodesk.unit.unit:kilovolts-1.0.1, KILOVOLTS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilowattHours-1.0.1, KILOWATT_HOURS
autodesk.unit.unit:kilowatts-1.0.1, KILOWATTS
autodesk.unit.unit:kipFeet-1.0.1, KIP_FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:kipFeetPerDegree-1.0.1, KIP_FEET_PER_DEGREE
autodesk.unit.unit:kipFeetPerDegreePerFoot-1.0.1, KIP_FEET_PER_DEGREE_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:kipFeetPerFoot-1.0.1, KIP_FEET_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:kips-1.0.1, KIPS
autodesk.unit.unit:kipsPerCubicFoot-1.0.1, KIPS_PER_CUBIC_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:kipsPerCubicInch-1.0.1, KIPS_PER_CUBIC_INCH
autodesk.unit.unit:kipsPerFoot-1.0.1, KIPS_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:kipsPerInch-1.0.1, KIPS_PER_INCH
autodesk.unit.unit:kipsPerSquareFoot-1.0.1, KIPS_PER_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:kipsPerSquareInch-1.0.1, KIPS_PER_SQUARE_INCH
autodesk.unit.unit:liters-1.0.1, LITERS
autodesk.unit.unit:litersPerHour-1.0.1, LITERS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:litersPerMinute-1.0.1, LITERS_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:litersPerSecond-1.0.1, LITERS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:litersPerSecondCubicMeter-1.0.1, LITERS_PER_SECOND_CUBIC_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:litersPerSecondKilowatt-1.0.1, LITERS_PER_SECOND_KILOWATT
autodesk.unit.unit:litersPerSecondSquareMeter-1.0.1, LITERS_PER_SECOND_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:lumens-1.0.1, LUMENS
autodesk.unit.unit:lumensPerWatt-1.0.1, LUMENS_PER_WATT
autodesk.unit.unit:lux-1.0.1, LUX
autodesk.unit.unit:meganewtonMeters-1.0.1, MEGANEWTON_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:meganewtonMetersPerMeter-1.0.1, MEGANEWTON_METERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:meganewtons-1.0.1, MEGANEWTONS
autodesk.unit.unit:meganewtonsPerMeter-1.0.1, MEGANEWTONS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:meganewtonsPerSquareMeter-1.0.1, MEGANEWTONS_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:megapascals-1.0.1, MEGAPASCALS
autodesk.unit.unit:meters-1.0.0, METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:metersOfWaterColumn-1.0.0, METERS_OF_WATER_COLUMN
autodesk.unit.unit:metersOfWaterColumnPerMeter-1.0.0, METERS_OF_WATER_COLUMN_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:metersPerKilonewton-1.0.0, METERS_PER_KILONEWTON
autodesk.unit.unit:metersPerSecond-1.0.1, METERS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:metersPerSecondSquared-1.0.1, METERS_PER_SECOND_SQUARED
autodesk.unit.unit:metersToTheFourthPower-1.0.1, METERS_TO_THE_FOURTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:metersToTheSixthPower-1.0.1, METERS_TO_THE_SIXTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:microinchesPerInchDegreeFahrenheit-1.0.1, MICROINCHES_PER_INCH_DEGREE_FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:micrometersPerMeterDegreeCelsius-1.0.1, MICROMETERS_PER_METER_DEGREE_CELSIUS
autodesk.unit.unit:miles-1.0.1, MILES
autodesk.unit.unit:milesPerHour-1.0.1, MILES_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:milesPerSecond-1.0.1, MILES_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:milesPerSecondSquared-1.0.1, MILES_PER_SECOND_SQUARED
autodesk.unit.unit:milliamperes-1.0.1, MILLIAMPERES
autodesk.unit.unit:milligrams-1.0.1, MILLIGRAMS
autodesk.unit.unit:millimeters-1.0.1, MILLIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:millimetersOfMercury-1.0.1, MILLIMETERS_OF_MERCURY
autodesk.unit.unit:millimetersOfWaterColumn-1.0.0, MILLIMETERS_OF_WATER_COLUMN
autodesk.unit.unit:millimetersOfWaterColumnPerMeter-1.0.0, MILLIMETERS_OF_WATER_COLUMN_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:millimetersToTheFourthPower-1.0.1, MILLIMETERS_TO_THE_FOURTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:millimetersToTheSixthPower-1.0.1, MILLIMETERS_TO_THE_SIXTH_POWER
autodesk.unit.unit:milliseconds-1.0.1, MILLISECONDS
autodesk.unit.unit:millivolts-1.0.1, MILLIVOLTS
autodesk.unit.unit:minutes-1.0.1, MINUTES
autodesk.unit.unit:nanograms-1.0.1, NANOGRAMS
autodesk.unit.unit:nanogramsPerPascalSecondSquareMeter-1.0.1, NANOGRAMS_PER_PASCAL_SECOND_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:newtonMeters-1.0.1, NEWTON_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:newtonMetersPerMeter-1.0.1, NEWTON_METERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:newtonSecondsPerSquareMeter-1.0.0, NEWTON_SECONDS_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:newtons-1.0.1, NEWTONS
autodesk.unit.unit:newtonsPerMeter-1.0.1, NEWTONS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:newtonsPerSquareMeter-1.0.1, NEWTONS_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:newtonsPerSquareMillimeter-1.0.1, NEWTONS_PER_SQUARE_MILLIMETER
autodesk.unit.unit:ohmMeters-1.0.1, OHM_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:ohms-1.0.1, OHMS
autodesk.unit.unit:pascalSeconds-1.0.1, PASCAL_SECONDS
autodesk.unit.unit:pascals-1.0.1, PASCALS
autodesk.unit.unit:pascalsPerMeter-1.0.1, PASCALS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:perMille-1.0.1, PER_MILLE
autodesk.unit.unit:percentage-1.0.1, PERCENTAGE
autodesk.unit.unit:pi-1.0.0, MULTIPLES_OF_
autodesk.unit.unit:poises-1.0.1, POISES
autodesk.unit.unit:poundForceFeet-1.0.1, POUND_FORCE_FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:poundForceFeetPerFoot-1.0.1, POUND_FORCE_FEET_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundForceSecondsPerSquareFoot-1.0.0, POUND_FORCE_SECONDS_PER_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundMassDegreesFahrenheit-1.0.0, POUND_MASS_DEGREES_FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsForce-1.0.1, POUNDS_FORCE
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsForcePerCubicFoot-1.0.1, POUNDS_FORCE_PER_CUBIC_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsForcePerFoot-1.0.1, POUNDS_FORCE_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsForcePerSquareFoot-1.0.1, POUNDS_FORCE_PER_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsForcePerSquareInch-1.0.1, POUNDS_FORCE_PER_SQUARE_INCH
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMass-1.0.1, POUNDS_MASS
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerCubicFoot-1.0.1, POUNDS_MASS_PER_CUBIC_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerCubicInch-1.0.1, POUNDS_MASS_PER_CUBIC_INCH
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerFoot-1.0.1, POUNDS_MASS_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerFootHour-1.0.1, POUNDS_MASS_PER_FOOT_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerFootSecond-1.0.1, POUNDS_MASS_PER_FOOT_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerHour-1.0.0, POUNDS_MASS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerMinute-1.0.0, POUNDS_MASS_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerPoundDegreeFahrenheit-1.0.0, POUNDS_MASS_PER_POUND_DEGREE_FAHRENHEIT
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerSecond-1.0.0, POUNDS_MASS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:poundsMassPerSquareFoot-1.0.1, POUNDS_MASS_PER_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:radians-1.0.0, RADIANS
autodesk.unit.unit:radiansPerSecond-1.0.1, RADIANS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:rankine-1.0.1, RANKINE
autodesk.unit.unit:rankineInterval-1.0.1, RANKINE_INTERVAL
autodesk.unit.unit:ratioTo1-1.0.0, RATIO_1
autodesk.unit.unit:ratioTo10-1.0.1, RATIO_10
autodesk.unit.unit:ratioTo12-1.0.1, RATIO_12
autodesk.unit.unit:revolutionsPerMinute-1.0.0, REVOLUTIONS_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:revolutionsPerSecond-1.0.0, REVOLUTIONS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:riseDividedBy1000Millimeters-1.0.1, RISE_1000_MILLIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:riseDividedBy10Feet-1.0.1, RISE_10_FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:riseDividedBy120Inches-1.0.1, RISE_120_INCHES
autodesk.unit.unit:riseDividedBy12Inches-1.0.1, RISE_12_INCHES
autodesk.unit.unit:riseDividedBy1Foot-1.0.1, RISE_1_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:seconds-1.0.0, SECONDS
autodesk.unit.unit:squareCentimeters-1.0.1, SQUARE_CENTIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:squareCentimetersPerMeter-1.0.1, SQUARE_CENTIMETERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:squareFeet-1.0.1, SQUARE_FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:squareFeetPer1000BritishThermalUnitsPerHour-1.0.1, SQUARE_FEET_PER_THOUSAND_BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:squareFeetPerFoot-1.0.1, SQUARE_FEET_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:squareFeetPerKip-1.0.1, SQUARE_FEET_PER_KIP
autodesk.unit.unit:squareFeetPerSecond-1.0.0, SQUARE_FEET_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:squareFeetPerTonOfRefrigeration-1.0.1, SQUARE_FEET_PER_TON_OF_REFRIGERATION
autodesk.unit.unit:squareHectometers-1.0.1, SQUARE_HECTOMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:squareInches-1.0.1, SQUARE_INCHES
autodesk.unit.unit:squareInchesPerFoot-1.0.1, SQUARE_INCHES_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMeterKelvinsPerWatt-1.0.1, SQUARE_METER_KELVINS_PER_WATT
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMeters-1.0.1, SQUARE_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMetersPerKilonewton-1.0.1, SQUARE_METERS_PER_KILONEWTON
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMetersPerKilowatt-1.0.1, SQUARE_METERS_PER_KILOWATT
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMetersPerMeter-1.0.1, SQUARE_METERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMetersPerSecond-1.0.0, SQUARE_METERS_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMillimeters-1.0.1, SQUARE_MILLIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMillimetersPerMeter-1.0.1, SQUARE_MILLIMETERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:squareYards-1.0.1, SQUARE_YARDS
autodesk.unit.unit:standardGravity-1.0.1, STANDARD_ACCELERATION_DUE_TO_GRAVITY
autodesk.unit.unit:steradians-1.0.0, STERADIANS
autodesk.unit.unit:therms-1.0.1, THERMS
autodesk.unit.unit:thousandBritishThermalUnitsPerHour-1.0.0, THOUSAND_BRITISH_THERMAL_UNITS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:tonneForceMeters-1.0.1, TONNE_FORCE_METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:tonneForceMetersPerMeter-1.0.1, TONNE_FORCE_METERS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:tonnes-1.0.1, TONNES
autodesk.unit.unit:tonnesForce-1.0.1, TONNES_FORCE
autodesk.unit.unit:tonnesForcePerMeter-1.0.1, TONNES_FORCE_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:tonnesForcePerSquareMeter-1.0.1, TONNES_FORCE_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:tonsOfRefrigeration-1.0.1, TONS_OF_REFRIGERATION
autodesk.unit.unit:turns-1.0.1, TURNS
autodesk.unit.unit:usGallons-1.0.1, US_GALLONS
autodesk.unit.unit:usGallonsPerHour-1.0.1, US_GALLONS_PER_HOUR
autodesk.unit.unit:usGallonsPerMinute-1.0.1, US_GALLONS_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:usSurveyFeet-1.0.0, US_SURVEY_FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:usTonnesForce-1.0.1, US_TONNES_FORCE
autodesk.unit.unit:usTonnesMass-1.0.1, US_TONNES_MASS
autodesk.unit.unit:voltAmperes-1.0.1, VOLT_AMPERES
autodesk.unit.unit:volts-1.0.1, VOLTS
autodesk.unit.unit:waterDensity4DegreesCelsius-1.0.0, WATER_DENSITY_AT_4_DEGREES_CELSIUS
autodesk.unit.unit:watts-1.0.1, WATTS
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerCubicFoot-1.0.1, WATTS_PER_CUBIC_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerCubicFootPerMinute-1.0.0, WATTS_PER_CUBIC_FOOT_PER_MINUTE
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerCubicMeter-1.0.1, WATTS_PER_CUBIC_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerCubicMeterPerSecond-1.0.0, WATTS_PER_CUBIC_METER_PER_SECOND
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerFoot-1.0.0, WATTS_PER_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerMeter-1.0.0, WATTS_PER_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerMeterKelvin-1.0.1, WATTS_PER_METER_KELVIN
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerSquareFoot-1.0.1, WATTS_PER_SQUARE_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerSquareMeter-1.0.1, WATTS_PER_SQUARE_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:wattsPerSquareMeterKelvin-1.0.1, WATTS_PER_SQUARE_METER_KELVIN
autodesk.unit.unit:yards-1.0.1, YARDS
autodesk.unit.unit:feetFractionalInches-1.0.0, FEET_AND_FRACTIONAL_INCHES
autodesk.unit.unit:fractionalInches-1.0.0, FRACTIONAL_INCHES
autodesk.unit.unit:metersCentimeters-1.0.0, METERS_AND_CENTIMETERS
autodesk.unit.unit:degreesMinutes-1.0.0, DEGREES_MINUTES_SECONDS
autodesk.unit.unit:slopeDegrees-1.0.0, SLOPE_DEGREES
autodesk.unit.unit:stationingFeet-1.0.0, FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:stationingMeters-1.0.0, METERS
autodesk.unit.unit:stationingSurveyFeet-1.0.0, US_SURVEY_FEET
autodesk.unit.unit:ampereHours-1.0.0, AMPERE_HOURS
autodesk.unit.unit:ampereSeconds-1.0.0, AMPERE_SECONDS
autodesk.unit.unit:circularMils-1.0.0, CIRCULAR_MILS
autodesk.unit.unit:coulombs-1.0.0, COULOMBS
autodesk.unit.unit:dynes-1.0.0, DYNES
autodesk.unit.unit:ergs-1.0.0, ERGS
autodesk.unit.unit:farads-1.0.0, FARADS
autodesk.unit.unit:feetPerKipFoot-1.0.1, FEET_PER_KIP_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:gammas-1.0.0, GAMMAS
autodesk.unit.unit:gauss-1.0.0, GAUSS
autodesk.unit.unit:henries-1.0.0, HENRIES
autodesk.unit.unit:maxwells-1.0.0, MAXWELLS
autodesk.unit.unit:metersPerKilonewtonMeter-1.0.1, METERS_PER_KILONEWTON_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:mhos-1.0.0, MHOS
autodesk.unit.unit:microns-1.0.0, MICRONS
autodesk.unit.unit:mils-1.0.0, MILS
autodesk.unit.unit:nauticalMiles-1.0.0, NAUTICAL_MILES
autodesk.unit.unit:oersteds-1.0.0, OERSTEDS
autodesk.unit.unit:ouncesForce-1.0.0, OUNCES_FORCE
autodesk.unit.unit:ouncesMass-1.0.0, OUNCES_MASS
autodesk.unit.unit:siemens-1.0.0, SIEMENS
autodesk.unit.unit:slugs-1.0.0, SLUGS
autodesk.unit.unit:squareFeetPerKipFoot-1.0.1, SQUARE_FEET_PER_KIP_FOOT
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMetersPerKilonewtonMeter-1.0.1, SQUARE_METERS_PER_KILONEWTON_METER
autodesk.unit.unit:squareMils-1.0.0, SQUARE_MILS
autodesk.unit.unit:webers-1.0.0, WEBERS
```