# Getting the model object properties in the right display units

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to show all the properties of a selected object in the viewer. Is there a method that translates the native model information taking in consideration the units selected by the user in the viewer config? That is, if the model contains information expressed in imperial units and the viewer's Display Unit is set as millimeters, is there a way to automatically convert the different units?

I found the autodesk.unit.unit list in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992151/autodesk-forge-is-returning-odd-measurement-data/64804998#64804998) related to Revit but I haven't found useful information about this topic in Forge documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the display unit by Viewer API, here is the code snippet:

```js
// Display units
viewer.prefs.set(Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Prefs.DISPLAY_UNITS, 'm');

// Display Units Precision
viewer.prefs.set(Autodesk.Viewing.Private.Prefs.DISPLAY_UNITS_PRECISION, 4);

//Get human-readable unit names
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.displayUnits

//Get values for changing display units
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.displayUnitsEnum

//Get human-readable Display Units Precisions
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.displayUnitsPrecision

//Get values for changing Display Units Precisions
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.displayUnitsPrecisionEnum
```

[image]

Or you can also consider using Profile settings: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/profiles/

```js
const customIfcProfileSettings = {
    settings: {
       displayUnits: 'm',
       displayUnitsPrecision: 4
    }
};
const customIfcProfile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(customIfcProfileSettings);
// Updates viewer settings encapsulated witihn a Profile.
// This method will also load and unload extensions referenced by the Profile.
viewer.setProfile(customIfcProfile);​
```

Comment: Thanks Eason. My question wasn't clear. We use Forge viewer to show the 3d models in our BIM platform. The user can read the properties of a selected object in a panel similar to the Forge properties panel. In this image [link](https://imgur.com/zhompPW) you can see on the left our panel and on the right the Forge one. Is it possible to get via a method the correct value formatted as the Forge panel? Eg. the Cost property in our panel has a mm unit, in Forge it is a currency $.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Gabriele. It looks like a model-related issue. What is your source format, Revit, or other formats? And what is your "left our panel," your custom panel in viewer or something else? and where is the data source?

Comment: If both panels are in Forge Viewer and the data source is from object properties. Could you try mouse click on the object and run `NOP_VIEWER.getProperties(NOP_VIEWER.getSelection()[0], console.log)` in the web browser console to see what the property display unit is.

Comment: If the model source format is Revit, then it would be related to which `parameter type` you selected when creating the property (parameter of Revit) in Revit Desktop. https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit/troubleshooting/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Revit-Model/files/GUID-28CBBEC2-6262-42D3-AE41-B36166E8318F-htm.html Maybe this property got a wrong parameter type selected.