# Sqlite properties DB - any documentation about the data types and unit symbols in the _objects_attr table?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Good Day,

is there any documentation about the data types and unit symbols in the sqlite properties database (_objects_attr table)?

Having looked at different files, the data types seem to map as follows:

- 1 - boolean
- 2 - integer
- 3 - float
- 11 - link/reference
- 20 - string
- 21 - element type
- 22 - date

The units (data_type_context) seem to vary per source file format.
Only floats have unit definitions.

For Revit, units are defined in a Revit specific way:

- https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2021/ENU/?guid=Revit_API_Revit_API_Developers_Guide_Introduction_Application_and_Document_Units_html
- [Autodesk Forge is returning odd measurement data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992151/autodesk-forge-is-returning-odd-measurement-data)

For other formats, SI and imperial unit symbols are used (mm, m, m^2, m^3, ft, ft^2, ft^3, radian, deg, ...)

Is this correct? Any documentation would help.

Many thanks

Wolfgang

Comment: Are you looking for this document that describes how the sqlite properties database is organized ? [SQLite Properties Database](https://github.com/wallabyway/propertyServer/blob/master/pipeline.md)

Comment: Hi AlexAR, thanks for your comment.
I know how the database is organized.
I'm looking for documentation about the data types and units.
Most of it is pretty obvious, but it would be good to get some documentation from Autodesk, or some confirmation that my interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The related questions show part of the answer and confirm the data types:

- [Data types in attributes table in SQLite database from Model Derivative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425612/data-types-in-attributes-table-in-sqlite-database-from-model-derivative?rq=2)
- [How to get property types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46619701/how-to-get-property-types/46621679#46621679)

Didn't find it when I searched ❓

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

> Here are the type values from the C++ code that performs properties extraction:

```
enum AttributeType {

  /* Numeric types */
  Unknown                 = 0,
    Boolean,
    Integer,
    Double,

    /* Special types */
    BLOB                    = 10,
    DbKey, /* reprensets a link to another object in the database, using database internal ID */

    /* String types */
    String                  = 20,
    LocalizableString,
    DateTime,       /* ISO 8601 date */
    GeoLocation,    /* LatLonHeight - ISO6709 Annex H string, e.g: "+27.5916+086.5640+8850/" for Mount Everest */
    Position        /* "x y z w" space separated string representing vector with 2,3 or 4 elements*/
};
```

Comment: The schemas used in the sqlite format are considered an implementation detail, and as such there's no official documentation for those. Also, we cannot guarantee that the schemas/data in the sqlite file will remain the same moving forward.